# how to call a method in a specific UIViewController in a tabviewcontroller from navigation bar button

Tags: objective-c

I have a tabViewController with 3 tabs each with it's own viewController of course.
I created a uibarbutton in navigation bar and would like to call a method on one of the UIViewController

```
UIBarButtonItem *deleteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(deleteAction:)];
deleteButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:deleteButton];


-(void)deleteAction:(id)sender
{
    NotesViewController *notesViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Notes"];
    [notesViewController.tableView setEditing:TRUE];

}
```

Although the above code doesn't throw error, it doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)deleteAction:(id)sender
{
    //NotesViewController *notesViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Notes"];

    NotesViewController *notesViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
    //[notesViewController toggleEdit:notesViewController];
    [notesViewController.tableView setEditing:TRUE];
}
```